# How can I skip to a template and render the request data to it using ajax?

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

This is the first page, in there I can use ajax to request url, and pass request data to it.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My ajax code is below:

```
     $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:'/app_api/server_payment/',
         contentType:'application/json',
         data:JSON.stringify({'params':buy_data}),
         dataType:'json',
         success:success_func
     })
     function success_func(response){
         console.log(response)
     }
```

In the views.py:

```
def server_payment(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_login = request.session['is_login']

        if is_login:

            print ('server_payment_2 ', is_login)  # it prints 
            return render(request, 'app_admin/payment.html')

        else:
            return render(request, 'frontend/login.html')
```

In the views.py I want to render the `payment.html` and skip to it.

This is my payment.html.

[image]

But the server.html page did not skip to the payment.html, and I don't know how to realize it.

I tried use the `self.location=/app_api/server_payment/` but I can not pass the data with post method.

There are some detail information in the first snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check AJAX header before you make any logic and return `JsonResponce` 
`request.is_ajax()`
More in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)

def server_payment(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    is_login = request.session['is_login']

    if is_login:

        print('server_payment_2 ', is_login)  # it prints
        if request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
        return render(request, 'app_admin/payment.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'frontend/login.html')
```

Comment: I read the doc find nothing useful. how can use it to realize it, can you be more detail?

Comment: I want to in the `server_payment()` function to redirect to `app_admin/payment.html` and render the request data in the template. you return the JsonResponse, the page will not switch.

Comment: In this case, as far as i know - you should change URL `windows.location...`

Comment: I tried use `self.location=xxx`,but I can not pass data now.

Comment: You should change `location` in Js code, in `success_func` i think

Comment: If do that, the data I want pass how to render to the final template.